# Creating a registration view in django, always getting an integrity error

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

So here's the function i wrote for the view:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        email = request.POST["email"]
        year = request.POST["Year"]
        form = registerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            branch = form.cleaned_data['branch']
        else:
            return render(request, "events/register.html", {
                "message": "You didn't provide all the fields",
                "form": registerForm()
            })
        if not email.endswith("ac.in"):
            return render(request, "events/register.html", {
                "message": "You must have an institution account",
                "form": registerForm()
            })

        # Ensure password matches confirmation
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]
        if password != confirmation:
            return render(request, "events/register.html", {
                "message": "Passwords must match.",
                "form": registerForm()
            })

        try:
            name = User.objects.get(email=email)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist :
            name = None

        # Attempt to create new user
        #Now This is where the problem is
        if name is None:
            user = User.objects.create(username=username, email=email, password=password,     year=year, branch=branch)
            user.save()
        else:
            return render(request, "events/register.html", {
                "message": "email already taken.",
                "form": registerForm()
            })
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("events:index"))
    else:
        ctx = { "form": registerForm() }
        return render(request, "events/register.html", ctx)
```

So when the form is submitted, i first check if an object with the entered username already exists, if it does than return the form with a message(email already taken). But everytime i try to create a new user, this message is returned and i am unable to create a User Object.
What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@musical_ant - Firstly, your view is extremely bloated with a lot of logic. You have so much business logic going on in the view which is supposed to serve a simple functionality - 'Register a User'.
What can be improved -

1. Password confirmation matching should be done over the client-side. Why would you want such a simple operation to happen at the backend when it can easily be done with some simple client-side Js?
2. You are getting some data by accessing the request payload and some from the form. Why is that? If you are rendering some sort of Django form or ModelForm why not used cleaned_data to get all the values. Or if you want to go through the request.POST because of some ajax call then use that ... Why are you mixing all these?

   ```
   if form.is_valid():
     branch = form.cleaned_data['branch']
   ```

This line made no sense to me. You are extracting a value if the form is valid. Ideally, if a form is valid, we call form. save(). And if it is not valid we check the form.errors()
3.

```
name = User.objects.get(email=email)
```

My question is you are checking if email exists in the User table,what if the username that the user has entered also exists in the user table and if I am not wrong username is supposed to be unique. Then won't this line throw an error if username already exists

```
user = User.objects.create(username=username, email=email, password=password,year=year, branch=branch)
    user.save()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  yeah i realized that i have to also check if the username that has been given already exists in the database, but even so, that doesn't explain why this view would throw an error when i am creating the first user (in an empty database) just after migrating. I think there's something else which is also going wrong